# ngDialog dark overlay covers the dialog

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to use the AngularJS ngDialog add-on to make a simple pop-up dialog. It basically works, but when the dialog appears, it starts out white but then quickly fades into the dark background. I assume there's some CSS conflict, but I can reproduce the problem with a very simple bit of HTML, below. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dialog Test</title>
    <link href='/assets/ngDialog/css/ngDialog.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src='/assets/angularjs/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='/assets/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.js'></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('dialogTest', ['ngDialog']);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='dialogTest'>
    <button ng-dialog='MY_DIALOG.html'>
      Dialog...
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you cannot replicate this with simple example, most possibly you will have other css that might be overriding rules like z-index... You can inspect styles on the overlay to see who is doing what

Comment: No, I'm saying that I *can* reproduce this with a simple example. See the included HTML.

Comment: hoops my bad!! Can you create a plunker?

Comment: Hmm, can't get the plunker to work. Never done one before, and Angular is producing an error.

Comment: I figured it out (my original problem, not plunker): I also need to include ngDialog's ngDialog-theme-default.css. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Also don't forget to specify `className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'` in your `ngDialog.open()` call

Comment: please post your comment as an answer so that it can be selected as the correct answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out (my original problem, not plunker): I also need to include ngDialog's ngDialog-theme-default.css. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: ugh... so simple. :))

Comment: ugh, they should update the documentation. thank you